# Cannot login in my django app after first time with django registration

Tags: django, authentication, django-registration

In my app I have used django-registration app with Student and Teacher models in it. In that I register a new user and log in for the first time and everything works fine. But I cannot log in again after I log out. Can anyone tell me why is this happening?

```
def accountLoginView(request):
    context= {}
    context['program_list'] = Program.objects.all()
    context.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response('general/account_login.html', context)
```

`

```
def accountAuthView(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username','')
#group = request.POST.get('group','')
     password = request.POST.get('password','')
     user = auth.authenticate(username=username,password=password)
     context= {}
     context.update(csrf(request))
# pdb.set_trace()
     if user is not None:
        try:
            Student.objects.get(user=request.user.id)
            is_student = True
        except Student.DoesNotExist:
            is_student = False
        try:
            Faculty.objects.get(user=request.user.id)
            is_faculty = True
        except Faculty.DoesNotExist:
            is_faculty = False
    # pdb.set_trace()
        if is_student == True:
           auth.login(request, user)
           return HttpResponseRedirect('/students')
       elif is_faculty == True:
           auth.login(request, user)
           return HttpResponseRedirect('/faculty')
class _RequestPassingFormView(FormView):
"""
A version of FormView which passes extra arguments to certain
methods, notably passing the HTTP request nearly everywhere, to
enable finer-grained processing.

"""
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # Pass request to get_form_class and get_form for per-request
    # form control.
    form_class = self.get_form_class(request)
    form = self.get_form(form_class)
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # Pass request to get_form_class and get_form for per-request
    # form control.
    form_class = self.get_form_class(request)
    form = self.get_form(form_class)
    if form.is_valid():
        # Pass request to form_valid.
        return self.form_valid(request, form)
    else:
        return self.form_invalid(form)

def get_form_class(self, request=None):
    return super(_RequestPassingFormView, self).get_form_class()

def get_form_kwargs(self, request=None, form_class=None):
    return super(_RequestPassingFormView, self).get_form_kwargs()

def get_initial(self, request=None):
    return super(_RequestPassingFormView, self).get_initial()

def get_success_url(self, request=None, user=None):
    # We need to be able to use the request and the new user when
    # constructing success_url.
    # pdb.set_trace()
    return super(_RequestPassingFormView, self).get_success_url()

def form_valid(self, form, request=None):
    return super(_RequestPassingFormView, self).form_valid(form)

def form_invalid(self, form, request=None):
    return super(_RequestPassingFormView, self).form_invalid(form)
```

RegistrationView:

```
class RegistrationView(_RequestPassingFormView):
    """
    Base class for user registration views.

    """
    disallowed_url = 'registration_disallowed'
    form_class = REGISTRATION_FORM
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'head', 'options', 'trace']
    success_url = None
    template_name = 'registration/registration_form.html'

    @method_decorator(sensitive_post_parameters('password1', 'password2'))
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Check that user signup is allowed before even bothering to
        dispatch or do other processing.

        """
        if not self.registration_allowed(request):
            return redirect(self.disallowed_url)
        return super(RegistrationView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, request, form):
        new_user = self.register(request, form)
        success_url = self.get_success_url(request, new_user)

        # success_url may be a simple string, or a tuple providing the
        # full argument set for redirect(). Attempting to unpack it
        # tells us which one it is.
        try:
            to, args, kwargs = success_url
            # pdb.set_trace()
            return redirect(to, *args, **kwargs)
        except ValueError:
            # pdb.set_trace()
            return redirect(success_url)

    def registration_allowed(self, request):
        """
        Override this to enable/disable user registration, either
        globally or on a per-request basis.

        """
        return True

    def register(self, request, form):
        """
        Implement user-registration logic here. Access to both the
        request and the full cleaned_data of the registration form is
        available here.

        """
        raise NotImplementedError
```

Comment: can you post your login and register view?

Comment: what error message does it give when you try to login after logging out? Does it just say that the username and password are incorrect?

Comment: also, can you show your student and faculty model? I want to know if it has a OneToOneField relationship with your user model.

Answer (score 0):

I beleive the issue is with the line:

```
Student.objects.get(user=request.user.id)
```

and

```
Faculty.objects.get(user=request.user.id)
```

You seem to be checking if the user object is equal to the request.user ID / pk value (which is an integer, not an object). So your code says "there is no student object or faculty object equivalent to request.user's ID / pk value. Then when you get to the if statements, both is_student and is_faculty return false so it does not do a redirect.

I'm not sure if your Student and Faculty model has a OneToOneField relationship with User, nor do I know what this relationship (if it exists) is called. I'm assuming that a OneToOneField relationship exists, and it is

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

With that assumption, try this code and let me know what error you get:

```
def accountAuthView(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username','')
     password = request.POST.get('password','')
     user = auth.authenticate(username=username,password=password)

     context= {}
     context.update(csrf(request))

     if user is not None: # if user exists
        try:
            Student.objects.get(user.id=request.user.id)
            is_student = True
        except Student.DoesNotExist:
            is_student = False
        try:
            Faculty.objects.get(user.id=request.user.id)
            is_faculty = True
        except Faculty.DoesNotExist:
            is_faculty = False

        if is_student == True:
           auth.login(request, user)
           return HttpResponseRedirect('/students')
       elif is_faculty == True:
           auth.login(request, user)
           return HttpResponseRedirect('/faculty')
       else: # what happens if the user is not student or faculty?
           auth.login(request, user)
           return HttpResponseRedirect('/notStudentOrFaculty')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I found the problem. The issue was with my authloginview() . Now I m simply using th login view provided by django in auth.contrib and everything seems to work fine.